# how to change position of a Number Pad?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

By default, if you set a UITextField keyboard type to Number Pad when it is displayed, it appears on the bottom of the screen. My problem is, if the controller has a toolbar, they can not appear when the keyboard appears. I want the number pad to appear on above toolbar. Can I change the position of it?

Any ideas?

[first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMR4D.png)

[second](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FI5yD.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you're not able to change the position of the system keyboard. You can however put the toolbar on top of the keyboard. There is a property on UIKeyboard that allows this. Look at  [inputAccessoryView.](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/InputViews/InputViews.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should listen for the various keyboard events, such as `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and adjust the constraints/frame of your toolbar accordingly. This will allow you to place your toolbar wherever you want when the keyboard is shown and dismissed.

Reference: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html